# Why do falling objects have incorrect terminal velocities in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm in the process of learning Unity and I've been experimenting with buoyancy and objects falling into water.  I've setup a simple test scene with a plane to simulate the ocean and cubes of various shapes and sizes to test the implementation.  I'm applying my own forces and I'm not using Unity physics for gravity, so I assume that's where the issue is coming in.  If I use Unity gravity the object falls much slower than applying the force of gravity myself.  Here's the setup:
[Cube Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUBvF.png)
[Output Velocity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7pVc.png)

The cube reaches terminal velocity in about fifty meters of falling and tops out at -9.61376 unity units.  My understanding of Unity is that the y value of the velocity vector is measured in units per second.  I'm using all standard units in this project, so one would assume that means the object is falling at 9.6 meters per second.  I'm using the standard gravity configuration of -9.81.

If we look at the expected terminal velocity (which we could easily just calculate online), we see the only unknown quantity in the calculation is Unity's value for atmospheric pressure and I don't see anywhere to configure it.  Terminal velocity is reached when the drag experienced by an object is equal to the weight of the object.  Drag is equal to air density (r) times velocity (v) squared divided by two, all that multiplied times the drag coefficient (Cd) and the cross sectional area (a). Something like this:
Cd*(r*v^2/2)*a

We know the coefficient of drag is 1 for this object, we set it in Unity.  We know the cross-sectional area should be 1 square meter (technically units).  All that we're left with is density * velocity squared divided by two.  We can solve for the terminal velocity of a 1 meter cube, by setting the weight equal to r*v^2/2 and solving for v (because, again, a body stops accelerating when drag equals weight).  I believe the standard atmospheric density is 1.204 kg/m^3 at sea level.  If we use that density and assume a weight of 1 kilogram we can solve for v as such, first we set weight to (9.81 * 1) or.
`9.81 = 1.204 * v^2 / 2  19.62 = 1.204 * v^2 16.2956 = v^2 v = 4.036`

That tracks with online calculations for the same parameters.  So what gives Unity?

I tried to drop a cube in Unity and expected it to fall at a rate predicted by Newtonian physics, it didn't.

Comment: Generally you should place all physics code in FixedUpdate() rather than Update().  This might also apply to simple _reading of velocities_. Try it and see.

Comment: I’m saying that, don’t forget that no where in Unity is there provision for specifying air temperature, air pressure for a given altitude so any airspeed (TAS, IAS or otherwise) shown in Unity is greatly simplified and unrealistic for any attempt of _out of the box flight simulator_ if that is your intent.  You’ll need to roll your own.

Comment: I'm not trying to make a flight simulator, I'm just trying to understand why Unity doesn't appear to follow the basic laws of physics.

Comment: I tried it with FixedUpdate and the result is the same.

Comment: _” I'm not trying to make a flight simulator, I'm just trying to understand why Unity doesn't appear to follow the basic laws of physics”_ - your first mistake was to attempt to model **drag** in something that has no concept of fluid dynamics let alone variable air density or temperature based on altitude.  My earlier hint should have been obvious for any remotely conversant in physics, flight simulator, falling cubes or not.  https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2021/10/17/flight-sim-project-update/

Comment: Additionally, Unity is a **game engine** and games along with **all** _online_ CGI takes liberties with reality.   Pretty sure there’s no conservation of energy going on with your falling cube hitting a table but no gamer is going to care either.   If you want reality, use an offline system like Renderman.

Comment: The physics engine models drag and you can clearly measure the effects of it's application with simple tests.  For my purposes, it's not really necessary that it's a completely accurate simulation of real-world conditions.  I just find it odd that it behaves this way.   I find objects seem to fall slowly anyway despite the fact that it's falling twice as fast as the real world model would suggest, so in a game you would probably want things to move a lot faster than they do in real life anyway.  That said I may use the in-engine physics for some things, I would like to know how it's modeled.

Answer (score 1):

Did some further research into this question and it appears that Unity just doesn't "simulate terminal velocity".  I found a post on the Unity forum from 2016 from a user employed by Unity, so I assume this is pretty accurate.  I couldn't find the specific code in RigidBody to verify, but the in-game behavior does seem to indicate that the way gravity is calculated, mass is irrelevant.

[Unity Forum Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r0r4.png)

I setup another test with cubes of various masses dropped from the same height with the same dimensions and drag and they do fall at the same velocity and impact at the same time, despite a 50% difference in mass.

So I guess the answer is, the way velocity is calculated in Unity physics the force of gravity is not proportional to mass (despite the fact that real life gravitational force = mass * acceleration of gravity).  Not sure if there was a performance motivation for this approach, but this seems like a bug.  Thinking about how to model drag, I get wanting to simplify it, but it's not a huge change to model it correctly.  I did it by turning gravity off and applying my own forces to the rigid body and modeling drag with the correct formula and it approximates real life (heavier objects fall faster given the same surface area and coefficient of drag).

**UPDATE**

I'll leave my previous comments despite the fact that they may be incorrect.  Reading more, I think it's fair to say Unity properly calculates the acceleration of gravity.  I'm sure it's just a misunderstanding of the physics involved on my part, but I find it odd that objects of different masses but identical drag will fall at the same rate. Gallileo's Leaning Tower of Pisa experiment proved that objects of different masses but identical drag will fall at the same rate.  I have a hard time rationalizing that result with Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation which states the force of gravity is equal to the product of masses of the two bodies divided by the distance between the bodies squared and the formula for terminal velocity which again is dependent on the mass of the falling object.

[NASA Terminal Velocity](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/VirtualAero/BottleRocket/airplane/termv.html)

Comment: _”the force of gravity is not proportional to mass”_ - that’s not Unity’s fault.  One does not need to take into account the mass of a space station as it orbits the Earth as the former is insignificant.  You are getting confused with n-Body motion where ones _does_ consider the mass of two stars because both are in the same league and both except forces on _eaxh other_.

Comment: …you seem to have a misunderstanding of fundamental physics.    All objects dropped at sea level fall at the same rate irrespective of mass and drag and has been proven in a vacuum.   As for Unity it has a very crude air model as any flight sim dev will tell you.  This is no surprise as all flight sims (except Xplane) fake air physics entirely with lookup tables in the interest of performance.

Comment: You are correct, in a vacuum that is true, in atmosphere objects are affected by drag which slows the descent of falling objects.  The terminal velocity of a skydiver can vary dramatically based on their orientation.  This is caused by reduced surface area and coefficient of drag.  Objects of different masses but equivalent drag will fall at different rates.  As usual, real life is a bit more complicated than a high-school physics class might have led you to believe.

Comment: I've been giving this more thought, I think it warrants a different question and I'll say that Unity's physics engine does correctly calculate the accelleration force of gravity.  Gallileo's famous leaning tower of Pisa experiment proved that objects of different masses but same surface area fall at the same rate in atmosphere.  Yet other, seemingly accurate models for gravitation would imply that mass is a factor such as Newton's law of universal gravitation and the formula for terminal velocity.